# Script to export attending, not attending and no response from Google Calendar into Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script

Can I export the guest list of Google Calendar of who is attending, who hasn't responded and not attending from Google Calendar into Google Sheets? Using a script? I am searching everywhere and just cant find what im looking for. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you'll get the event and then getGuestList(), then you'll go through each guest one at a time and use the getGuestStatus on them.

Comment: Thank you :) I will try figure it out. Much appreciated